# Wireless 802.1x : configure tls, peap and ttls out of the box with FreeRadius 3.0.8 on a Mac Yosemite

Tags: macos, security, wireless, freeradius, osx-yosemite

I'm looking for a quick easy way to bring up my testbed. No need to worry about default settings because this is just for testing. I just need to get 802.1x working on 3 modes PEAP, TTLS and TLS on my MacBookPro. My set up is quite simple with a Airport 11ac and a Mac Mini on Yosemite 10.10.3 that i will use to install FreeRadius. The client is a MacbookPro that i will be authenticated against the network. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i've got from : 
http://wiki.freeradius.org/building/Build
and 
kb.meraki.com/knowledge_base/freeradius-configure-freeradius-to-work-with-eap-tls-authentication

1) Install talloc and FreeRadius

curl -LO www.samba.org/ftp/talloc/talloc-2.1.0.tar.gz
 tar zxvf talloc-2.1.0.tar.gz
 cd talloc-2.1.0
./configure --without-gettext
 make
 sudo make install

cd ../
 curl -LO ftp.freeradius.org/pub/freeradius/freeradius-server-3.0.8.tar.gz
 tar zxvf freeradius-server-3.0.8.tar.gz
 cd freeradius-server-3.0.8
./configure --enable-developer
 make
 sudo make install

NOTE: while installing free radius, notice that toward the end, bootstrap is being called. That's when your certificate is being generated.

2) Edit /usr/local/etc/raddb/users with:

```
user    Cleartext-Password := "whatever"
        Reply-Message := "whatever"

bob     Cleartext-Password := "hello"
        Reply-Message := "Hello, %{User-Name}"
```

3) Edit /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap:
    default_eap_type = md5 change to default_eap_type = tls
    private_key_file = ${certdir}/server.pem change to server.key

4) Edit clients.conf with your Airport Extreme's ip

```
client ExtremeAnger {
        ipaddr = 192.168.5.1
        secret = wireless
}
```

5) Start FreeRadius on MacMini with 
 sudo /usr/local/sbin/radiusd -X

6) Copy ca.der and client.p12 to MacBookPro

7) Go to MacBookPro and install Apple Configuration app from the App Store

8) Under 'Supervise' menu, click the plus + sign , create new profile

a. Fill out General tab with the name of the cert, 
b. go to WiFi tab, enter ssid and security type (tls),
c. go to Identity Certificate and load the client.p12 file,
d. go to Certificates tab and load the ca.der file
e. go back to WiFi tab, Trust menu, check box the Example Certificate Authority that appears after you are done with step d.

9) Save and go back to main menu of the Apple Configuration, click the export arrow button and SaveAs a profile, you will get abc.mobileconfig file

10) Double click on this profile on the MacBookPro and try to authenticate to your Airport Extreme's 802.1x network ssid.

11) Pray that it will work on first try, if not , read the logs that comes out on the screen of your MacMini's Radius -X window

12) Create another profile for PEAP and TTLS from Apple Configurator App.
Make sure you use the username bob and pw hello as configured above (if you haven't figured it out yet, username 'user' and pw 'whatever' is used for tls mode)

Thanks for reading

Comment: to be able to edit files under raddb, log in as root by doing 'sudo -i'

Comment: Forgot to mention about the Airport Extreme configuration. Go to Airport Ultilities, Wireless Security --> WPA2Enterprise. Configure RADIUS with ip of the MacMini and the shared secrete is 'wireless'